# android - search and replace in string java android

Tags: java, android, string

This is a part of a string

```
test="some text" test2="othertext"
```

It contains a lot more of similar text with same formating. Each "statment" is separate by empty space 
How to search by name(test, test2) and replace its values(stuff between "")?
in java

I dont know if its clear enough but i dont know how else to explain it

I want to search for "test" and replace its content with something else

replace 
test="**some text**" test2="othertext"
with something else

Edit:
This is a content of a file

```
  test="some text" test2="othertext"
```

I read content of that file in a string

Now i want to replace **some text** with something else

**some text** is not static it can be anything

Comment: Please give an example to explain what you want to do.

Comment: So you want to delete the value of "test" if its present in "test2", right ?

Comment: just replace content of test with something else

Comment: your problem is still not clear. that's the time to post some part of code, where you want to implement it.

Comment: for example change this **test="some text"** to be this **test="something else"**

Comment: Please be more precise with your example so we could know : what situation you could have, and what result you want to get. Because it still not clear for me.

Comment: No, it's not clear.  Show text before replace and text after replace with a description of why.

Comment: I have a file containing **test="some text" test2="othertext"** and other stuff. I read it in as String. now i want to replace part of string that is content of test(between "") with something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the** `replace()` **method of String, which comes in 3 types and 4 variants:**

- `revStr.replace(oldChar, newChar)`
- `revStr.replace(target, replacement)`
- `revStr.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`
- `revStr.replaceFirst(regex, replacement)`

**Eg:**

```
String myString = "Here is the home of the home of the Stars";
myString = myString.replace("home","heaven");
```

**///////////////////// Edited Part //////////////////////////////////////**

```
String s = "The quick brown fox test =\"jumped over\" the \"lazy\" dog";
String lastStr = new String();
String t = new String();

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("test\\s*=\\s*\".*\"");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);

        while (mat.find()) {

            // arL.add(mat.group());
            lastStr = mat.group();

        }

Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("\".*\"");
        Matcher mat1 = pat1.matcher(lastStr);

        while (mat1.find()) {

            t = mat.replaceAll("test=" + "\"Hello\"");

        }

        System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: its not that simple. in the example from first post i need to search for **test** and replace everything between "" after test=

Answer (score 1):

So you want to replace every instance of "test" with something else?

Let's say the string name is myString:

```
myString = myString.replace("test","something else");
```

Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: no. I have a file containing **test="some text" test2="othertext"** and other stuff. I read it in as String. now i want to replace part of string that is content of test(between "") with something else

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking that you fetch data from file in the form of string,
lets suppose, your string is,

> String s = "My name="sahil" and my company="microsoft", also i live in
>   country="india"".

Now you want to replace "sahil" with "mahajan" and "microsoft" with "google".

I have tried experimenting with the string methods to implement this functionality, but didnt find a relavent result. But i could provide you with some methods. You could use **regionMatches**, **indexOf("name="")**. But these functions will help you in finding where *sahil*(suppose) is located. but the replcae function here is difficult to work, because it replaces character sequence, for which you should know the exact character sequence.

Now you might try experimenting with the string methods. It could help.

Comment: yes. finally. that's what i want. but sahil can be anything it isnt static

Comment: from which type of file, you are getting the data, is it an xml file or any other txt file.?

Comment: i know how to read content of that file in a string, just dont know how to search/replace

Comment: Is it okay to replcae the text manually or you want it to do programmatically.? The most convenient way to do it, is to first read the file, then show in edit text and then you can manually replace the text which you want.

Comment: no, it must be programmatically. that process needs to be done without user interaction

Comment: Ok. how about removing the whole name="something". is there a way to do that. than adding it again with new value

Comment: No, you cant do it. you dont know what's in there in place of **something**. you exactly need to write the replacable character sequence. Even you cant do like this, **string.replace("name="sahil"", "mahajan");**, because two double quotes will give an error.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
String mFileContents;
private void replaceValue(String name, String newValue) {
    int nameIndex = mFileContents.indexOf(name);
    int equalSignIndex = mFileContents.indexOf("=", nameIndex);
    int oldValueIndex = equalSignIndex + 2;
    int oldValueLength = mFileContents.indexOf("\"", oldValueIndex);
    String oldValue = mFileContents.substring(oldValueIndex, oldValueLength);

    String firstHalf = mFileContents.substring(0, oldValueIndex -1);
    String secondHalf = mFileContents.substring(oldValueIndex);
    secondHalf.replaceFirst(oldValue, newValue);

    mFileContents = firstHalf + secondHalf;
}
```

Comment: this returns original string but without first "

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "some text";
    a = a.replace("text", "inserted value");
    System.out.print(a);
```

Try this

Comment: test isnt string its part of other string

Comment: i dont have a code. i dont know how to start. All i did so far is read a content of a file in String